# Alamofire not sending header

Tags: python, django, swift, alamofire

I'm not able to send my authentication token using Alamofire, and I'm using the same structure as I've seen in many other examples:

```
var get =  Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://127.0.0.1:8000/practice/userList/18", headers: ["Authorization": "Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b"])
            .responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)

        }
```

Using the curl request be I can see the token, but no header appears at all with Alamofire. The request is still processed but the header remains missing.

```
curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:ist/18/ -H 'Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b'
```

Thanks to anyone who can help this I've been trying to figure it out for for hours with no luck.

Answer (score 5):

Put a slash at the end of the URL. Worked fine for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

still not sure why the version I posted wasnt working, but the below code works fine!

```
let token = "9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b"

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/practice/userList/18/")
    var mutableRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    mutableRequest.setValue("Token \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    mutableRequest.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    var manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
    var get = manager.request(mutableRequest)
```